# ROS node from Gazebo plugin is not showing in the rosnode list

Tags: gazebo-11

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I want to publish some topics from a Gazebo model plugin to the ROS topic, so I use the C++ ROS node initiation code from some example that I now only copy-paste to all plugins I need.

```
// Initialize ros, if it has not already been initialized.
std::string node_name = std::string("my_node_name");
if (!ros::isInitialized()) {
  int argc = 0;
  char **argv = nullptr;

  ros::init(argc, argv, node_name. ros::init_options::NoSigintHandler);
}

// Create ROS node.
this->rosNode.reset(new ros::NodeHandle(node_name));

topic_name = "/my_topic";
this->rosPublisher = this->rosNode->advertise<std_msgs::Float64>(topic_name, 1);
```

The `/my_topic` topic is registered (I can see it in the `rostopic list`), I publish to the topic messages on every update (I debugged that the code is being executed, so the messages are being send in the plugin) but when I use `rostopic echo /my_node` nothing is being printed.

Also using `rosnode list` shows me no `/my_node_name` node. I'm thinking the node either isn't created at all, or shuts down. I don't know. How can I check for that, or launch the node correctly, or what else could be going wrong?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/25736/ros-node-from-gazebo-plugin-is-not-showing-in-the-rosnode-list/) by [kumpakri](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6511/kumpakri/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 755 on 2020-08-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

A ros node is initialized by the [gazebo_ros_api](https://github.com/ros-simulation/gazebo_ros_pkgs/blob/kinetic-devel/gazebo_ros/src/gazebo_ros_api_plugin.cpp#L122) system plugin. It's the `/gazebo` you see on the node list. Since the plugins are run in the same process, you can only have 1 node, the /gazebo one.

Having another node for your plugin is not necessary. If you want to keep your plugin independent from everything else, you can just configure the ros backend accordingly

```
ros::NodeHandle nh;
ros::CallbackQueue callback_queue;
ros::AsyncSpinner spinner(1, &callback_queue);
nh.setCallbackQueue(&callback_queue);
spinner.start();
```

---

Originally posted by [nlamprian](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/8391/nlamprian/) with karma: 833 on 2020-08-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kumpakri](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6511/kumpakri/) on 2020-08-24**:
I be damned but this approach actually solved the issue with messages not being printed from the echo. Thank you.

**Comment by [m.bahno](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/29530/m.bahno/) on 2020-08-26**:
I'm having some difficulties using this. Whenever subscriber callback is to be called in a plugin with ros set like this, gazebo falls with segmentation fault. There are also other plugins set up like this, might that be the problem? Everything works fine without `nh.setCallbackQueue(&callback_queue)`. Is setting the callback queue to the node handle neccessary or is it enough to set it for the spinner?

**Comment by [nlamprian](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/8391/nlamprian/) on 2020-08-26**:
Setting the callback in the node handle is necessary. Otherwise, messages you publish will go into the default queue of the node. Just make sure you don't have a thread of your own servicing the same queue.

**Comment by [m.bahno](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/29530/m.bahno/) on 2020-10-20**:
Thank you [nlamprian](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/8391/nlamprian/)! I just got to it again and my problem was more programatical. I fought with instancing of those classes. In case someone has similar problem, I attach part of my solution for class members:

**Comment by [m.bahno](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/29530/m.bahno/) on 2020-10-20**:
.cc

```
this->rosNode.reset(new ros::NodeHandle());
this->spinner = new ros::AsyncSpinner(1, this->callback_queue);
this->rosNode->setCallbackQueue(this->callback_queue);
this->spinner->start();
```

**Comment by [m.bahno](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/29530/m.bahno/) on 2020-10-20**:
.hh

```
std::unique_ptr<ros::NodeHandle> rosNode;
ros::CallbackQueue *callback_queue;
ros::AsyncSpinner *spinner;
```

**Comment by [m.bahno](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/29530/m.bahno/) on 2021-03-22**:
I have another question: How is this implementation of AsyncSpinner different from the one usually used in [this](https://github.com/ros-simulation/gazebo_ros_pkgs/blob/kinetic-devel/gazebo_plugins/src/gazebo_ros_planar_move.cpp) tutorial? Specifically the section 3. Is AsyncSpinner just implementation of this approach, or there are some differences?

**Comment by [nlamprian](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/8391/nlamprian/) on 2021-03-24**:
The two options are effectively the same. In the referenced plugin, a thread is created to spin the queue. The asyncspinner here has its own thread (and potentially more) for the queue.

**Comment by [m.bahno](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/29530/m.bahno/) on 2021-03-31**:
Thank you for clearing that! Of course I did insert a wrong link (I meant [this](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?cat=guided_i&tut=guided_i6), actually containing section 3). But the principle is the same, so I add this for future readers.